# Windows 7 Aero theme when on battery

Tags: windows-7, power-management

Windows 7 has the full and basic [Aero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Aero) themes that can be changed inside personalization. Windows used to automatically disable Windows Aero (transparency) when I unplug my laptop from the mains.

I reset the theme, and now it doesn't do this anymore. How do I enable this again?

I've checked the advanced power options and control panel but turning back on this feature is eluding me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I got it working.

1. Change the power profile to "Power Saver" (How to: Right click on the battery icon on the desktop > select "Power options" > Select "Power Saver")
2. **Unplug** the charger and then go to "Personalize" (right click on the desktop select "Personalize ")
3. Click windows color > switch **OFF** "Enable Transparency"
4. Save changes and exit "Personalize"
5. **Plug in** the charger and then go to "Personalize" (right click on the desktop select "Personalize")
6. Click windows color > switch **ON** "Enable Transparency"
7. Save changes and exit "Personalize"

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Wonderful, that did the trick. Thanks for the great answer

Comment: It seems to me the automatic change of transparency is hard linked to the Power Saver energy strategy. Can anyone suggest where this link might be?

Answer (score 2):

Check the power management settings. It should be in the advanced settings.

Not at a laptop at the moment, but Power Options > Change Advanced Settings

You may need to click on the link to 'view options not visible' (or something to that effect)

Comment: Nope.​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the visual settings in Windows to "Let Windows choose what's best for my computer".

*Start -> Right Click Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced (tab) -> Performance: Settings -> Check "Let Windows choose what's best for my computer"*

**REBOOT PC**

Windows will now disable the aero transparent effect when running on the power saver mode unplugged. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

On my Dell Inspiron 15R, it was the Dell software that was the culprit.

Right Click on the battery icon » Dell Battery Meter » Uncheck "Enable
Dell Extended Battery Life".

Then Click Settings below this  and uncheck the 'Switch to Windows 7 basic' option.

Comment: Not quite word-for-word what I wanted, but contained enough of the same words to find it on my battery icon's menu.  Which enabled me to turn the feature off, so I wouldn't have to wait so long for Windows to toss out all those textures every time I unplugged my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if turn off the theme is supposed to happen, because I can't think of a reason for [this](http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/10/26/aerofoil-extends-windows-7-notebook-battery-life/) software to exist if it did. In any case, that software exists, and looks to work quite well :)

Comment: You'd be surprised just how much software is written that duplicates some existing function because somebody didn't like what was there (justifiably or not), or because they wanted to figure out how to do it themselves, or just for the hell of it.

Comment: I think that this software will let you switch between entire power profiles on state change of the mains. Windows only provides limited settings within a single profile. It doesn't let you switch profiles completely.

Comment: Windows 7 re-vamped a lot of the power management controls. Dig in to the advanced settings and take a look.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer (a Dell) there is an section in the Advanced power settings called Dell Additional settings.  The options in there let you turn off Aero Glass and the sidebar when on battery.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Vista Battery Saver](http://www.codeplex.com/vistabattery). It works fine on Windows 7 as I use it myself. Not only can you have it disable Aero when on battery, you can have it switch between power profiles. For instance, I have my laptop run on high performance when plugged in and then it switches to the battery saver profile when running off of the battery.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried this, I posted last time, but it' still wouldn't change automatically. Try opening til Performance Windows while being in the power saver mode, then choose to disable the aero glass, then goto balanced power scheme, then choose "let windows choose what's best..." now it should work, but it seems that you have to choose it when ur in power saver mode.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Aerofoil](http://silentdevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/aerofoil-151-released.html) I'm using it for years now since Vista RTM and it saved me alot of battery life, it can disable Aero and change the power plan when you're on battery.